# Return SQL Query as bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, psql

First Post. Bash novice. Couldn't find an effective solution.

Looking for an efficient parsing method / alternative method

My initial attempt: (+ edit thanks to @larks)

```
services=($($PSQL "SELECT array(select name from services);"))

echo ${services[@]}
>array -------------------------------- {Shampoo,Dying,Long-cut} (1 row)
echo ${#services[@]}
>5
echo ${services[2]}
>{Shampoo,Dying,Long-cut}
```

I'm looking to end up with an array identical to the ones below but without creating a csv in the process.

```
echo $($PSQL "\copy (select name from services) to 'services.csv';")

readarray arr -t a < services.csv
echo ${arr[@]}
>Shampoo Dying Long-cut
echo ${#services[@]}
>3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `services` variable is not an array; to create an array you need to surround the value with `(...)`. For example, compare this:

```
$ example=$(echo one two three)
$ echo ${example[0]}
one two three
```

With this:

```
$ example=( $(echo one two three) )
$ echo ${example[0]}
one
```

So assuming that your `$PSQL` command generates output in an appropriate format, you want:

```
services=( $($PSQL "SELECT array(select name from services);") )
```

---

For what you're trying to do in your question, I don't see any reason to use the `array` function. Given a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE services (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO services (name) VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO services (name) VALUES ('bar');
INSERT INTO services (name) VALUES ('qux');
```

A query like this will produce results amendable for turning into a bash array:

```
$ psql -t --csv  -U postgres -d arraytest -c 'select name from services'
foo
bar
qux
```

In a bash script:

```
services=( $(psql -t --csv  -U postgres -d arraytest -c 'select name from services') )

for service in "${services[@]}"; do
  echo "SERVICE: $service"
done
```

Which produces:

```
SERVICE: foo
SERVICE: bar
SERVICE: qux
```

Comment: Noted. But your fix still gives me the exact same output but with an array of 5 elements. Where...
    echo ${#services[@]}
    >5
     echo ${services[2]}
    >{Shampoo,Dying,Long-cut}

I could then read this element into a new array but I was hoping for a more elegant solution